# Hibernate Search with Eclipse Link

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

Does anyone know if I can use Hibernate Search with Eclipse Link?  Or do I have to use Hibernate as my JPA provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate search can't be used with another JPA provider... sorry

You have 2 options :

- switch to Hibernate as your JPA provider
- use EclipseLink with Solr (and SolrJ java API)

Comment: thank you for your responses.  I do have another, general question for you.  Do people use straight lucene and then manually update the indexes when the DB changes?  What are issues with doing it this way?

Comment: My company is using Lucene without solr, there is no 'issue' to do it in this way. All is about what do you want to index and in which way. For example I don't see usage of solr with a desktop application as solr works in a web server... you can take a look at http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-vs-solr.html or http://www.findbestopensource.com/article-detail/lucene-vs-solr for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on a integration of the Hibernate Search Engine that supports any JPA provider you throw at it. It's currently in, hmmm. let's call it late Alpha. Most features work (but I wouldn't suggest using it in production just yet) and you can give it a try with:

https://github.com/s4ke/hibernate-search-genericjpa-example

Some differences for your domain model are:

1. additional @InIndex annotation for every entity in the index
2. if you want automatic indexing of your domain model you currently need @Updates annotated tables that map the information about changes in your model.

For more information visit: https://github.com/Hotware/Hibernate-Search-JPA

Comment: interesting, I'll take a look.  However, I have written my own indexing/search integration for Lucene, so I probably won't be able to test it out...

Comment: I'd be interested in what you think about it :)

Comment: Did you make any progress? With `hibernate-search` 5.7.0.Final I'm still getting `org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Trying to use Hibernate Search without an Hibernate EntityManager: class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl` and the dependencies of your github project are no longer available.

Comment: Sadly, currently I don't have time to further development, but I just checked and the dependencies definitely are available. Just install via "mvn clean install -DskipTests". If you want a standalone, use the standalone module, otherwise use hibernate-search-genericjpa.